# Hi, I am facing the problem with cross browser testing. I am not getting launched two browser at simultaneously

Tags: java, maven, selenium, automation, testng

I have passed the browser parameters through XML file and handled in the script also. But currently, two browsers are getting launched sequentially not simultaneously.

See my XML structure below,

1. XML suite file:

[TestNG Test Suite File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGm3N.png)

If you see the above link image, I have passed the two browsers as parameters. I have handled the passed browsers parameters in the @BeforeTest method in the script. Is my XML suite file correct? Am I passing the parameters correctly?

Why I am getting two browsers launched at sequentially? Please suggest the solution.

Comment: You probably want `parallel="tests"` but there's a lot more to running tests in parallel in testNG than just that.  I just spent over a month with trial-and-error learning how to convert an existing framework to run in parallel.  Also add thread-count as suggested in the answer below.  Avoid static methods and web elements, Research THREAD_LOCAL variables.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using,

```
<suite name="My suite" parallel="methods" thread-count="5">
<suite name="My suite" parallel="tests" thread-count="5">
<suite name="My suite" parallel="instances" thread-count="5">
```

and your method should like this,

```
@Test(threadPoolSize = 3, invocationCount = 10,  timeOut = 10000)
public void testServer() {}
```

Each test suite will get executed in separate thread,
Here is three suite .xml files gets executed in separate threads,

```
java org.testng.TestNG -suitethreadpoolsize 3 testng1.xml testng2.xml testng3.xml
```

and remember that you can instruct TestNG to run your tests in separate threads in various ways.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for you replay. I am getting launched two browsers at a time. But, currently only one instance is getting launched at a time of Chrome and FF browsers. How to launch multiple instances of each at a time? I have given the thread count in xml suite file but it doesn't works.